# change plist dic/string via osx-terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, plist

I'm trying to change two sting keys within a dictionary plist file with the os x onboard tools (via terminal) but I'm having problems. I just switched back to os x after a 10 years break so I'm struggling a bit atm.

[plist data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPrbC.png)

```
% plutil -p "/Users/username/Library/Preferences/com.Adobe.Common 15.0.plist"                                                          
    {
      "Media Cache" => {
        "DatabasePath" => "/Users/path/somewhere/one"
        "FolderPath" => "/Users/path/somewhere/two"
      }
    }
```

I tried several command wiht defaults write, plutil & PlistBuddy but I'm not able to change the values to anything else.

```
% defaults write "/Users/username/Library/Preferences/com.Adobe.Common\ 15.0.plist" "Media Cache" -array-add '{DatabasePath = (test);}'
```

Could someone help me with this problem? The empty spaces aren't perfect but I have to deal with them...

Best,
Ben

Comment: If you happen to have XCode you can edit plist files with it easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `defaults` you can change or set your keys this way

```
defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/com.Adobe.Common\ 15.0.plist "Media Cache" -dict DatabasePath "/Users/path/somewhere/one" FolderPath "/Users/path/somewhere/two"
```

From man

> ```
>  -dict       Allows the user to add a dictionary to the defaults database
>              for a domain.  Keys and values are specified in order:
>
>                    defaults write somedomain preferenceKey -dict key1 value1 key2 value2
> ```

Comment: Thanks @schmidt9 - the defaults version works awesome. I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with **plutil** in 3 steps

1. Convert to human-readable form:

```
plutil -convert json -r ~/Library/Preferences/com.Adobe.Common\ 15.0.plist -o ~/my.plist.json
```

2. Edit **my.plist.json** in a text editor.
3. Convert back to binary plist:

```
plutil -convert binary1 ~/my.plist.json -o ~/Library/Preferences/com.Adobe.Common\ 15.0.plist
```

Or, you can try **PlistBuddy** as described here:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/282732/how-do-i-replace-a-value-in-an-plist-array-using-plutil